# Update SQL query using UNIX time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, session

I would like to test the following garbage collector code on a database of sessions.
It should be following the conditions below:

- if 'remember me' is enabled by the user, then it should delete all rows which are not active within 2 weeks.
- if 'remember me' is disabled by the user, then it should delete all rows which are not active within 30 minutes.

I have times inserted in the `LAST_ACTIVITY` column, with the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` format.

```
public function gc( $maxlifetime )
{
    $this->conn->SQL( 'DELETE FROM session WHERE (LAST_ACTIVITY < ? AND REMEMBERUSER = ?) OR (LAST_ACTIVITY < ? AND REMEMBERUSER = ?)' , 
        [ strtotime('-30 minutes'), 'N' , strtotime('-2 weeks'), 'Y']);
    return true;
}
```

Are the `AND` or `OR` operators working properly? I would only like to test the SQL query, and not the gc method.

Comment: This probably belongs on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

#### Observations

- Your `$maxlifetime` parameter is unused.
- One of the conditions is redundant: any session older than two weeks should be discarded unconditionally.
- The capitalization of your column names is unconventional.  Usually, identifiers are `lowercase`, and SQL keywords are `ALL CAPS`.  (Note: identifiers in MySQL are [case-sensitive on Unix, but not Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2009005/1157100).)

#### Proposal

```
DELETE FROM session
    WHERE last_activity < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
    OR (rememberuser = 'N' AND last_activity < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);
```

#### Advantages

- This is a fixed query with no parameters, which keeps things simple.
- It's almost English-like in readability.

#### Caveats

- This requires your `last_activity` column to be of the `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` type.  You could also make it work with integer Unix timestamps instead, using

  ```
  DELETE FROM session
      WHERE last_activity < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
      OR (rememberuser = 'N' AND last_activity < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE));
  ```
- This assumes that the `last_activity` times were set according to the database server's clock, not the application server's clock.  Otherwise, if they are running on separate machines, or if you are careless with your treatment of timezones, you could end up with clock skew.  Therefore, it's best to pick one clock and stick with it consistently.  I prefer to use the database server's clock, for several reasons:

  1. If your application runs on multiple application servers, all connecting to a central database, then the database clock is the natural official time source.
  2. Your queries can be simpler, as illustrated above.
  3. Storing the timestamps in a `DATETIME` column is more meaningful than storing them as integers.

  So, to make this work, the `last_activity` times have to be inserted or updated using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` or `NOW()`, or established by default when a `TIMEZONE` column has no specified value.
- Admittedly, this formulation uses MySQL-specific date / time functions, so it is less portable.  Similar solutions exist for other database systems, though.